# Why execution time of MongoDB SQL in Navicat is different from the time show in explain() function？

Tags: mongodb, navicat

The MongoDB runs on a CentOS(7.5) server.
First, I execute one SQL in Navicat, the execution time is 6.991s.

```
db.getCollection("analysis").find()
> OK
> 时间: 6.991s
```

But when I use explain() function of MongoDB, the executionTimeMillis is 0 like this.

```
db.getCollection("analysis").find().explain('executionStats')
> OK
> 时间: 0.038s
```

```
    "executionStats": {
        "executionSuccess": true,
        "nReturned": NumberInt("987"),
        "executionTimeMillis": NumberInt("0"),
        "totalKeysExamined": NumberInt("0"),
        "totalDocsExamined": NumberInt("987"),
        "executionStages": {
            "stage": "COLLSCAN",
            "nReturned": NumberInt("987"),
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate": NumberInt("0"),
            "works": NumberInt("989"),
            "advanced": NumberInt("987"),
            "needTime": NumberInt("1"),
            "needYield": NumberInt("0"),
            "saveState": NumberInt("7"),
            "restoreState": NumberInt("7"),
            "isEOF": NumberInt("1"),
            "invalidates": NumberInt("0"),
            "direction": "forward",
            "docsExamined": NumberInt("987")
        }
    },
```

What's the reason?

Comment: Did you run these multiple times?  I would think that after the first query all of the documents would be in the cache, so the second query doesn't need to wait for them to be fetched from disk.

Comment: @Joe I tried multiple times but returned the same result. I think because find() returns a cursor, so the time in explain() function is the time of getting the cursor, not the time of getting all of the documents.

Comment: when you run with "executionStats" it does fetch all of the documents.  Although the time to transfer them to the client is not included.

Comment: @Joe yep, maybe the time converting data to BSON takes a long time. Some fields in my collection contain complex nested documents.